# Why is my terrain not rendering properly?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

Currently, I have a random terrain generator, which I am sure works properly, however, when I attempt to build a set of `VertexPositionColor`, it does not render properly. This is what I currently have (overhead view):
[image: overhead view]

My code:

```
List<VertexPositionColor> w = new List<VertexPositionColor>();
int width = 20;
int height = 20;
float terrainScale = 2.0f;
long seed = (DateTime.Now.Millisecond + DateTime.Now.Second * DateTime.Now.Hour);
ProceduralLayeredMapGenerator plmg = new ProceduralLayeredMapGenerator(seed);
Random rand = new Random((int)seed);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3();
        position.X = x;//(x - width / 2) * terrainScale;
        position.Z = y;//(y - height / 2) * terrainScale;
        float point = plmg.getPoint(x, y);
        Color computedColor = new Color(rand.Next(255), rand.Next(255), rand.Next(255));
        position.Y = (point * 2);
        w.Add(new VertexPositionColor(position, computedColor));
    }
}
colors = w.ToArray();
```

And then the drawing code:

```
foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, colors, 0, colors.Length / 3, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
}
```

How can I get it to look something more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw a TriangleStrip then you must add the vertices in the order in which they will be used to draw the triangles; right now you're adding vertices top-to-bottom, left-to-right.  Also, to render a height map like that you'll need to use multiple TriangleStrips.